# Apache Kylin - how to solve cube build error problem

Tags: bigdata, data-analysis, data-warehouse, kylin

When i built kylin_sales_cube in Apache Kylin,i get the error:

`ERROR [main] org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.KylinReducer:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.setStoragePolicy(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Ljava/lang/String;)V`

when i built my own cube,i got same error.

please help!

versions: kylin3.1.3 hadoop2.7.3 hbase1.7.1 hive2.3.9

Answer (score 0):

It looks like kylin 3.1 and hadoop 2.7 are not compatible. Maybe try kylin < 2.5 ?

You can find more info about compatibility here:

https://kylin.apache.org/docs31/install/index.html

Comment: if it helps please accept the answer

Comment: It works. Thanks.